# How to show/save the HTML including pictures as currently shown by the web browser?

Tags: browser, html

When I display a webpage and want to see the source code, most times it only shows the source code without modifications done by JavaScript. Saving the website seems to download the original again.

**How can I save the HTML including pictures etc. which is currently shown by the webbrowser?**

I tried (sorry if translations are incorrect, I'm on a German system):

- IE: File / Save as --> redownloads original
- IE: right click, view source --> only original HTML
- Opera: File/Save --> only original HTML
- Opera: right click, source --> only original HTML
- Opera: Dragonfly --> dynamic HTML, but how to save?
- Firefox: right click: view page source --> original HTML
- Firefox: Inspector --> dynamic HTML, can copy to clipboard
- Firefox: File/Save as --> this seems to work

Firefox seems to be the only browser which does it the way I like (actually I'd like to be able to choose between the two modes). Is this also possible in the other browsers?

Update:

Consider this example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
var rot13 = String.prototype.rot13 = function(s)
{
  return (s = (s) ? s : this).split('').map(function(_)
  {
    if (!_.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) return _;
    c = _.charCodeAt(0)>=96;
    k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96 + 12) % 26 + 1;
    return String.fromCharCode(k + (c ? 96 : 64));
  }
  ).join('');
};
document.write("<img src=\"");
document.write("uggc://jryyvfbyhgvbaf.qr/qr/jc-pbagrag/tnyyrel/oyraqre-m-ohssre/purpxznex.wct".rot13());
document.write("\"/>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to save the HTML file including the image. IE and Opera do not save the image.

I'd like to do it in other browsers than Firefox for valid reasons, e.g.

- some websites work better in IE (like Sharepoint)
- some websites do not support Opera very well

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, you have: File menu > Save as ..., which allows you to save all webpage
files as Web Page, Complete (which is a multi-file/folder format), or as Web Archive (which is a single-file format).

In Firefox, you have File menu > Save page as ..., which also can save all website files as
Web Page, Complete and if you have the Mozilla Archive Format extension installed, you can save in the MAFF format.

Comment: Yes, IE does it, but it saves the HTML as delivered by the webserver, not as it is displayed on the screen. As stated in my question, Firefox seems to work.